# ¿Cuando usar decltype y auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

Buenas, sé que ambos realizan la deducción de tipos, pero ¿Cual es la diferencia entre ambos? ¿Cuándo es mas conveniente usar `decltype` sobre `auto` y viceversa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` permite deducir el tipo a partir del valor con el que se inicia la variable:

```
auto i = 5;   // int
auto f = 4.5; // double
```

Sin embargo `auto` no es capaz de cubrir todo el abanico de posibilidades...

Imagínate que tienes que programar una plantilla tal que:

```
tipo1 func(objeto)
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }
```

¿Cómo programas esa plantilla?

**versión 1**

```
auto func(auto objeto)
{
  return objeto.otraFunc();
}
```

Válido en C++17, no así en C++11

**versión 2**

```
template<class T, class U>
T func(U objeto)
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }
```

Compatible con todas las versiones pero un poco engorroso de usar, ya que si bien el tipo `U` se puede deducir automáticamente el tipo `T` habrá que indicarlo de forma explícita:

```
struct POO
{
  int otraFunc()
  { return 5; }
};

POO MiObjeto;
std::cout << func<int>(MiObjeto);
```

**versión 2.1**

Con el fin de deducir los dos valores creamos una estructura intermedia a modo de *traits*:

```
struct POO
{
  int otraFunc()
  { return 5; }
};

// Implementación por defecto = no valida
template<class T>
struct traits;

template<>
struct traits<POO>
{
  typedef int returnType;
};

template<class T>
typename traits<T>::returnType func(T objeto)
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }


int main()
{
  POO MiObjeto;
  std::cout << func(MiObjeto);
}
```

Aunque es facil entender que esta solución empieza a ser bastante engorrosa.

**versión 3**

... o también podemos usar `decltype`

```
struct POO
{
  int otraFunc()
  { return 5; }
};

template<class T>
decltype(T().otraFunc()) func(T objeto)
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }

    int main()
{
  POO MiObjeto;
  std::cout << func(MiObjeto);
}
```

En este caso, `decltype` evalúa la expresión `T().otraFunc()` que no es más que:

- `T()`: Simula la creación de un nuevo objeto de tipo `T`
- `T().otraFunc()` simula la llamada y se queda con el tipo de retorno de la función `otraFunc` para el tipo `T`

Podría suceder que el constructor por defecto `T` no estuviese disponible para un tipo dado... en cuyo caso la expresión anterior no podría ser evaluada... Podemos obtener una versión más genérica usando punteros:

```
template<class T>
decltype(((T*)nullptr)->otraFunc()) func(T objeto)
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }
```

Como `decltype` **no ejecuta código** sino que simplemente lo evalúa no hay riesgo de fugas de memoria ni de llamadas sobre objetos no válidos... claro que tampoco podemos usar `new`...

Por cierto, hay gente que prefiere esta otra nomenclatura totalmente válida en C++11

```
template<class T>
auto func(T objeto) -> decltype(((T*)nullptr)->otraFunc())
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }
```

Por supuesto `decltype` también se puede utilizar para evaluar expresiones más sencillas:

```
decltype(5) var = 4; // decltype(5) == int
std::cout << var;    // imprime 4

float foo();
decltype(foo()) var2 = 4.5// float

decltype(var2) var3 = 3; // float
```

---

**EDITO**

Otra forma de usar `decltype`, en combinación con `declval`. Así no tenemos que preocuparnos por cómo se debe crear el objeto `T`:

```
template<class T>
auto func(T objeto) -> decltype(std::declval<T&>().otraFunc())
{ return objeto.otraFunc(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cuándo es mas conveniente usar `decltype` sobre `auto` y viceversa?

`decltype` y `auto` no son intercambiables ni equivalentes, su uso, comportamiento y cometido es diferente.

`auto` es un declarador que deduce tipos en lugares en que pueda hacerse una declaración con inicialización:

- Si el inicializador es un literal deducirá el tipo (no constante) del literal.
- Si el inicializador es una referencia, ignorará la referencia.
- Si el inicializador está calificado con `const` o `volatile`, estos calificadores se ignorarán si se aplican sobre el objeto (calificadores de primer nivel).
- Si el inicializador es una expresión, deducirá el tipo (no constante) resultante de evaluar la expresión (teniendo en cuenta los puntos anteriores).
- Si el inicializador es una función, deducirá el tipo de retorno de la función (teniendo en cuenta los puntos anteriores).

`decltype(...)` es un declarador que copia el tipo de algo ya existente:

- Si entre sus paréntesis hay un literal, deducirá el tipo (no constante) del mismo.
- Si entre sus paréntesis hay una expresión o una función, deducirá el tipo resultante de evaluar dicha expresión (sin llegar a evaluarla) o función (sin realizar la llamada).
- Si entre sus paréntesis hay una expresión entre paréntesis, la tratará como Valor del lado Izquierdo y deducirá referencia.

En cuanto a cuándo usarlos, como cualquier herramienta: Cuando sea necesario.

#### ¿Cuándo es necesario?

Hay cosas que no se pueden programar sin la ayuda de `auto` y `decltype`; suelen ser cosas que son imposibles (o difíciles) de conocer por el programador pero triviales para el compilador como por ejemplo operaciones entre tipos desconocidos:

```
template <typename I, typename D>
auto suma(I i, D d) -> decltype(i + d)
{
    return i + d;
}
```

En el contexto de la función plantilla `suma` es imposible para el programador saber el tipo de retorno de la función, no sabemos qué tipo es `I` ni qué tipo es `D` y no lo sabremos hasta el momento de instanciar la plantilla, pero ¡no podemos cambiar la plantilla en tiempo de compilación!.

Por suerte el compilador tiene esa información que al programador le falta y sabe, en el momento de instanciar la plantilla, qué tipos son `I` y `D`, en este contexto `auto` le dice al compilador: "*No se qué tipo de retorno tiene la función pero se deducirá luego*" mientras que `decltype` le dice "*Deduce el tipo de la expresión `i + d` y asígnalo al retorno de la función `suma`*".

Así pues:

- `suma(1, 2.f)` tiene como tipo de retorno `float`.
- `suma<std::string>("patatas", " fritas!")` tiene como tipo de retorno `std::string`.

Por el mismo motivo que nos lleva a desconocer el tipo de retorno de esta función, no podemos crear una variable para capturar su valor:

```
template <typename I, typename D>
auto suma(I i, D d) -> decltype(i + d)
{
    return i + d;
}

template <typename I, typename D, typename ... T>
auto super_suma(I i, D d, T ... tipos)
{
    ???? sub_suma = suma(i, d);
 // ~~~~ <--- que tipo debo usar aqui?

    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) >= 2)
        return sub_suma + super_suma(tipos ...);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) == 1)
        return sub_suma + std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(tipos ...));
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) == 0)
        return sub_suma;
}
```

En la variable `sub_suma` de la función `super_suma` vuelve la deducción estática de tipos (`auto`) al rescate:

```
template <typename I, typename D, typename ... T>
auto super_suma(I i, D d, T ... tipos)
{
    auto sub_suma = suma(i, d);
 // ~~~~ <--- Deja que el compilador lo deduzca por ti!

    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) >= 2)
        return sub_suma + super_suma(tipos ...);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) == 1)
        return sub_suma + std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(tipos ...));
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tipos) == 0)
        return sub_suma;
}
```

Nótese que `super_suma` no usa `-> decltype` tras la definición; esta es una característica de C++14 conocida como [Deduccion del tipo de retorno en funciones](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/deduccion-de-tipo-de-retorno-en-funciones/).

#### Limitaciones de `auto` y `decltype`

La manera en que funciona `auto` hace que sea imposible deducir referencias a no ser que se haga explícitamente:

```
const std::string TEXTO_CONSTANTE("Hola mundo!");

auto f1() { return TEXTO_CONSTANTE; } // auto deduce std::string
auto &f2() { return TEXTO_CONSTANTE; } // auto deduce const std::string &
```

Si quisiéramos deducir implícitamente el retorno como `const` (que es el tipo real) deberíamos apoyarnos en `decltype`:

```
const std::string TEXTO_CONSTANTE("Hola mundo!");
// auto deduce const std::string
auto f1() -> decltype(TEXTO_CONSTANTE) { return TEXTO_CONSTANTE; }
```

A partir de C++14 es posible combinar `decltype` y `auto` de manera más directa para deducir el tipo real de retorno de una función usando `decltype(auto)`:

```
const std::string TEXTO_CONSTANTE("Hola mundo!");
// Estilo C++11 auto deduce const std::string
auto f1() -> decltype(TEXTO_CONSTANTE) { return TEXTO_CONSTANTE; }
// Estilo C++14 auto deduce const std::string
decltype(auto) f2() { return TEXTO_CONSTANTE; }
```

#### A veces no es necesario, pero es útil.

El declarador `auto` nos permite obviar el tipo en sitios en que normalmente tenemos que duplicarlo, por ejemplo esto:

```
auto monstruosidad = new std::map<std::pair<std::size_t, std::uint64_t>, std::u32string>();
```

Es más cómodo de leer que esto:

```
std::map<std::pair<std::size_t, std::uint64_t>, std::u32string> *monstruosidad = new std::map<std::pair<std::size_t, std::uint64_t>, std::u32string>;
```

También nos permite obviar por completo el tipo así que esto:

```
auto insercion = monstruosidad->insert({{0, 0}, u32"Patata frita!"});
```

Es más cómodo de leer que esto:

```
std::pair<std::map<std::pair<std::size_t, std::uint64_t>, std::u32string>::iterator, bool> insercion = monstruosidad->insert({{0, 0}, u32"Patata frita!"});
```

Este tipo de uso de `auto` ha dado lugar a una tendencia llamada "*Casi siempre `auto`*" (en Inglés "*Almost Always Auto*" o AAA, término acuñado por [Herb Sutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Sutter)) que nos aconseja usar `auto` en casi todas las situaciones. [El artículo](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) dedicado a AAA es excelente<sup>1</sup>, traduciré tan sólo las partes que considero más relevantes:

> #### Pereza y compromiso
>
> Primero pereza: “escribir `auto` para declarar una variable es principalmente para teclear menos” es una preocupación común . Sin embargo, esto es una malinterpretación del cometido de `auto`. [...], las razones principales para declarar variables usando `auto` son la correctitud, rendimiento, mantenibilidad, robustez y si, conveniencia, pero es la última de la lista.
>
> Segundo, compromiso: “Pero en algunos casos quiero comprometerme con un tipo específico, no deducirlo automáticamente, así que no puedo usar `auto`.” Es verdad que a veces necesitas comprometerte con un tipo específico, pero aún en ese caso puedes usar `auto`. [...], no sólo puedes escribir declaraciones como `auto x = tipo{ inicializador };` (en lugar de `tipo x{inicializador};`) para comprometerte con un tipo específico, además hay buenas razones para hacerlo, como que por ejemplo `auto` significa que no puedes olvidarte de inicializar la variable.
>
> #### (I)legibilidad
>
> El [...] más común de los argumentos es sobre legibilidad: “Mi código se vuelve ilegible muy rápido cuando no conozco con exactitud el tipo de mis variables a no ser que explore el retorno de la función o expresión, así que no puedo usar `auto` siempre.” Hay verdad en esto, incluyendo la posibilidad de poder buscar tipos específicos al usar sintaxis sin tipo `auto x = expresion;` [...] así que esto podría parecer un buen argumento. Y es cierto que cualquier característica puede ser usada en exceso. Sin embargo, creo que este argumento es más débil de lo que parece por cuatro razones, dos menores y dos mayores.
>
> Los dos contrargumentos menores son:
>
> - La parte de “no puedo usar `auto`” no es verdad, pues como acabamos de ver antes puedes explicitar el tipo y seguir usando `auto`, con buenos beneficios.
> - Este argumento no se aplica si estás usando un [EDI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado), porque siempre podrás conocer el tipo exacto, por ejemplo situando el cursor sobre la variable. Garantizado, esto se pierde cuando dejas atrás el EDI, por ejemplo al imprimir el código.
>
> Los dos contrargumentos mayores son:
>
> - Muestra una preferencia por programar implementaciones, no interfaces. Comprometerse en exceso con tipos explícitos hace que el código sea menos genérico y más interdependiente, y en consecuencia más frágil y limitado. [...]
> - Nosotros (es decir, tú) ya ignoramos tipos específicos contínuamente…

---

<sup>1</sup>Aunque no coincido por completo con el mismo.